Is ontological nihilism logically equivalent to bundle theory?
I think there is a paradigm in ontology based on predicate logic that the domain of discourse that the variables range over does not refer to conceptual entities. Rather, I think of the variables as “referents” which predicates get attached to.
For example, you could say that x refers to the person “Bob”, and to assert that he is tall, use a predicate tall(x). But if we pursue the aforementioned strategy, x is not anything but a locus for predication. That is to say, we could say Bob(x) and Person(x) and tall(x) to mean there is something that is Bob / called Bob, is a person, and is tall.
I read that Quine may have favored the latter view and that this has been called ontological nihilism.
But it reminds me of the concise explanation of David Hume’s bundle theory, which posits that objects are wholly defined in terms of the ontological category of “properties”.
Are these more or less the same notion, or how might they differ?
These are some passages that made me wonder if a connection could be drawn between the two:

"The speaker of predicate-functorese effectively talks in predicates. Imagine, however, that she was introduced to the concept of a subject. This concept offers her a choice. On the one hand, she may posit a univocal subject — the Absolute — and let the predicates just be modifiers of it. It is unclear to me if such would capture what Spinoza and various idealists thought, but no matter: the Absolute would make true our truths. On the other hand, she could go nihilist by way of appending a pleonastic subject to her predicates. On this view, every sentence would have the form familiar from ‘It’s raining’: It is such that F, in general. The idea of rendering all of our claims into feature-placement claims, such as weather reports, often goes by the name of ontological nihilism, and can be endorsed independently of the virtues of predicate-functor logic. My present claim, following Burgess, is not that ontological nihilism should be accepted, but simply that it is a position a speaker of predicate-functorese may adopt."


John Collins (see Conifold)

Quine invented predicate-functor logic.

Bundle theory, originated by the 18th century Scottish philosopher David Hume, is the ontological theory about objecthood in which an object consists only of a collection (bundle) of properties, relations or tropes.. According to bundle theory, an object consists of its properties and nothing more; thus, there cannot be an object without properties and one cannot conceive of such an object. For example, when we think of an apple, we think of its properties: redness, roundness, being a type of fruit, etc. There is nothing above and beyond these properties; the apple is nothing more than the collection of its properties. In particular, there is no substance in which the properties are inherent.


Wikipedia, Bundle Theory


Quine is never known as ontological nihilist but have commitments to the values of  bound variables, and a bundle of fibers have different such values for each idiosyncratic fiber like different sorts in FOL...

Quine was an ontological relativist. Wrote an essay on it. Ontological nihilism has something to do with rejecting concrete entities, and as someone who advocated a very specific ontological criterion of existence,  I'm rather sure no one has attributed the term to his metaontological theory.

Not even close. Quine favored the opposite of the view you ascribe to him:"A theory is committed to those and only those entities to which the bound variables of the theory must be capable of referring". Hume's bundle theory concerns only the 'self' and does not reduce objects to placeholders in a structure generally. That sounds more like structural realism, but it is not ontological nihilism either.

The TLDR is just as Conifold briefly makes the case. There is no deep connection between Hume and Quine, and you mischaracterize Quine.
Quine Is Not an Ontological Nihilist
Conifold said:

Not even close. Quine favored the opposite of the view you ascribe to him:"A theory is committed to those and only those entities to which the bound variables of the theory must be capable of referring". Hume's bundle theory concerns only the 'self' and does not reduce objects to placeholders in a structure generally. That sounds more like structural realism, but it is not ontological nihilism either

Willard Quine has a very explicit view on ontological commitment (a term he coined), that had to do with existential quantification, and he was not a nihilist. You can oversimplify by saying that if you declare it within the context of a variable and and assign a count, it exists. More accurately in his words from the WP article:

the general adoption of class variables of quantification ushers in a theory whose laws were not in general expressible in the antecedent levels of logic. The price paid for this increased power is ontological: objects of a special and abstract kind, viz. classes, are now presupposed. Formally it is precisely in allowing quantification over class variables α, β, etc., that we assume a range of values for these variables to refer to. To be assumed as an entity is to be assumed as a value of a variable. (Methods of Logic, 1950, p. 228) (emphasis mine)

For a more sophisticated reading, see Ontological Commitment (SEP). Needless to say this is not remotely ontological nihilism. From WP:

Extreme metaphysical nihilism, also sometimes called ontological nihilism, is the position that nothing actually exists at all.

So, we can see clearly Quine doesn't seem to fit the bill, though as I mentioned before, Quine is associated with ontological relativism, his work being cited in the SEP's Ontological Commitment.
Hume's Bundle Theory
Bundle theory is from 2 centuries prior. From WP:

Bundle theory, originated by the 18th century Scottish philosopher David Hume, is the ontological theory about objecthood in which an object consists only of a collection (bundle) of properties, relations or tropes.

Here, we see an ontological perspective that might be an early form of scientific reduction (SEP) such that objects are reduced to their properties. And reductionism governs the language of science to some degree regarding the relationship of theories in the philosophy of science, so if borrow a page from Quine who sees science and philosophy as continuous, it seems we can properly use the language of reduction to answer your question:
You ask:

Is ontological nihilism logically equivalent to bundle theory?

While both theories are metaontological because they assert claims about what ontological topics, the former existential quantification as a basis of ontological commitment and the latter how ontological entities can be reduced to properties, Quine's theory cannot in any obvious way be reduced to Hume's, and certainly Hume's theory doesn't seem to obviously reduce to Quines. Thus, we can conclude the two metaontological theories are relatively independent of each other.
The Quotations Provided
You emphasized:

The idea of rendering all of our claims into feature-placement claims, such as weather reports, often goes by the name of ontological nihilism, and can be endorsed independently of the virtues of predicate-functor logic. My present claim, following Burgess, is not that ontological nihilism should be accepted, but simply that it is a position a speaker of predicate-functorese may adopt."

So, this seems to suggest that predicate functor logic (outside of my readings of Quine given it's emphasis on formal logic) allows the formal logic of PFL to presume in its metalanguage a presumption about ontological commitment inherent in the formal syntax. Hence, the question goes not to Quine's meta-ontology, but another philosopher's meta-ontological interpretations of PFL. It seems you are suggesting that the predicates in natural language used by Hume's bundle theory may in some way be related to the idea that predicates in PFL designed by Quine somehow constitute an endorsement of ontological nihilism on Quine's behalf. Given Conifold's endorsement of my own intuitions, and further examination, I do not see this to be the case.

Makes sense why certain questions are closed. This site struggles with broader philosophical cultural issues and often presents a narrow, well-"bundled" model-centric automatism that is quite dangerous, don't you think?

@Peirceverance I'd say, particularly given my posts in meta, that certain questions make sense when closed, some make none, and some closures are a form of sensitive dependence on initial conditions which, like strange attractors, seem to manifest some form of statistical regularity with glaring individual outliers that deviate from a mysterious and constantly shifting measure of central tendency. I liken this site to warfare, where one should never be cocky, never be certain, and never say never. ; )

@Peirceverance It's also an oddly only partially satisfying experience of having some of the smartest people capable of extremely sophisticated articulation constantly come and go leaving a mild, nostalgic bitterness for real discourse with whole human beings, a sucralose of intellectual sweetness, as it were.

It was more nostalgia rather than bitterness--the Schellings, Hegels, Whiteheads, or Wittgensteins of the world would not be able to cross the rubicon of cancel culture broligarchy.
